# serialPersistentFields in Java

Tags: java, serialization

While serializing a class in Java, you could take use of `serialPersistentFields` to override the default Java serialization behaviour.

Suppose, I want to serialize a static List, then I need to define it in an array of `ObjectStreamField` objects.

Can someone please help me to give an actual implementation of this whole scenario ?

Comment: There is an example in the Java Object Serialization Specification: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#6250

Comment: I have already went through that doc. I just wanted to have an example which could put that concept to use for both Serialization and de-serialization end. Another point to that doc, the approaches have been given, but, the differentiation from Externalizable is not given.

Comment: *"For Externalizable objects, only the identity of the class of the object is saved by the container; the class must save and restore the contents. "*  - In other words, an `Externalizable` object is responsible for its own serialization.  The spec goes on to say how it must do this.

Answer (score 3):

There is an example using `serialPersistentFields` in the Java Object Serialization Specification: [Section 1.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#6250).  The text says that the example code works for serialization and deserialization.

My reading of the code is that if one of the fields in your `serialPersistentFields` is a static field of the class, then it will be included in the serialization.  However serialization of statics like this is dubious practice.  The problem is understanding what happens when you deserialize a class with serialized statics.  Will this clobber the existing static of the target class, or throw away the serialized static?  Neither of these is a good option (in general).

Comment: Yes. I have seen the example on the doc. But, does this concept find it's uses in any java classes. If this type of functionality is provided, what advantage has custom serialization over default one then.

Comment: The advantages of custom serialization (in general) can be to avoid serialization of specific fields (that are inherently non-serializable ... or not required), to get a more efficient serial representation than the default one, or to do non-standard things during serialization or deserialization; e.g. add an instance to a lookup table on deserialization.

Comment: Some of the standard collection classes do custom serialization and deserialization.  Look at the source code.